# Definition of Orientable in O'Neill's

Tags: differential-geometry, terminology

In O'Neill's *Elementary Differential Geometry*, orientable is defined as follows: A surface M is orientable if there exists a differentiable (or merely continuous) 2-form on M that is nonzero at every point of M.

Is not continuity a weaker condition than differentiability? Can I take this definition to mean that the 2-form is continuous?

Comment: It turns out that it doesn't matter whether your nonzero 2-form is continuous or differentiable, so you can take it to mean either. Certainly continuity of a 2-form is weaker in general, but for an orientation we can always replace a merely continuous 2-form with an equivalent smooth 2-form, so it doesn't matter here.

Comment: Is it too early for me to ask why? I only took the first course in undergrad diff geo.

Comment: It's not too early to ask why. I'm on mobile right now, so I can't give a proper answer, but the proof that a continuous orientation form can be replaced by a smooth one goes roughly like this. Choose a cover of your surface by connected coordinate charts $U_i$. If $\omega_0$ is your continuous nonvanishing 2-form, then $\omega_0|_{U_i}=f_i dx\wedge dy$, with $f_i$ continuous and nonzero. Note that this implies that either $f_i$ is positive everywhere or negative everywhere. Let $\epsilon_i$ be $\pm 1$ for each $i$ according to whether $f_i$ is positive or negative.

Comment: Then take a smooth partition of unity subordinate to our cover, $\rho_i$, and define $\omega=\sum_i \rho_i\epsilon_i dx_i\wedge dy_i$ ($x_i$ and $y_i$ being the coordinates on $U_i$). Now $\omega$ is smooth, and if we examine the value of $\omega$ at a point $p$ on $u,v\in T_pM$, we see that $\omega_p(u,v)=\sum_i \rho_i(p)\epsilon_i (dx_i\wedge dy_i)(u,v)=\sum_i \rho_i(p) \frac{f_i(p)(dx_i\wedge dy_i)(u,v)}{|f_i(p)|}=\sum_i \rho_i(p) \frac{\omega_0(u,v)}{|f_i(p)|=\omega_0(u,v)\frac{\rho_i(p)}{|f_i(p)|}$. Thus $\omega$ is a positive scalar multiple of $\omega_0$ everywhere.

Comment: Thus $\omega$ is nonvanishing, smooth, and equivalent to $\omega_0$. Hopefully there aren't too many typos. As I mentioned, I'm on mobile, so I can't proofread very well, since it doesn't render properly. I'll fix any errors or typos later.